# Deleting extra space in column names in pandas

Tags: python

I have a sample dataframe called `df` with following column names;

```
col_names=[' 24- hour Indicator Yes/No', 'Time of Transaction', ' Date of Transaction']
```

As you can see some values are misaligned, for example extra space at the beginning or end of the string, say ' 24- hour Indicator Yes/No'.
Is it possible to do some data cleaning in order to get rid of that unwanted space in column names.
My present approach is right now manual;

```
df['Date of Transaction']  = df[' Date of Transaction']
df.drop(columns=[' Date of Transaction'],\
          axis=1,inplace=True)
```

But it will be nice to have a function in order to avoid reassigning values and dropping columns.
Kindly advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) function:

```
df.rename(str.strip, axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lstrip()` in column names, it will remove leading spaces:

```
df.columns.str.lstrip()
```